# can some one help me with a syntax error on python

Tags: python, python-3.x

please help me with this code as I have tried many different things and can't get it to work. thank you for all of your help.

```
print(" Greenfly Population Model")
chocies=[]


def option0():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("GOOD BYE")
    time.sleep(1)
    # exiting the loop

def option1():
    if choies==[]:
        print("Set the Generation 0 values!")
    else:
        print(chocies[:])
def option2():
    print("Display the Generation 0 values")


def option3():
    print("Run the model")

def option4():
    print("Export data")

def option5():
    print("Quit")





import time#for option 0
while True:#to keep the program continuous
    option=int(input("""
    High Scores


0- Exit
1- Show score
2- Add a score
3- Delete a score
4 - Sort the score in ascending order
5- Sort the score in descending order
""")#all different options


s = int(input("from the menu above please pick your choice"))
print("setting the generation 0 values"))
i = int(input("Enter the number of generations you want the model to run for (must be between 5 and 25 inclusive")):
m = int(input("Choose adult survival rate between 0 and 1:"))
o = int(input("Choose Juvenile survival rate between 0 and 1:"))
n = int(input("Choose Senile survival rate between 0 and 1:"))
r = int(input("please enter the initial numbers of juvenile:"))
a = int(input("please enter the initial numbers of adults:"))
i = int(input("please enter the initial numbers of seniles:"))
v = int(input("please enter the initial numbers of the adults:"))

print(s)
print(i)
print(m)
print(o)
print(n)
print(r)
print(a)
print(i)
print(v)



print(" Greenfly Population Model")
option=int(input("""
High Scores


0- Exit
1- Show score
2- Add a score
3- Delete a score
4 - Sort the score in ascending order
5 - Sort the score in descending order
""")#all different options
```

my syntax error is

```
s = int(input("from the menu above please pick your choice"))
```

the s is where my syntax error

Comment: Be more specific in your question and the part of code that doesn't work.

Comment: There's a closing parenthesis missing on the previous line.

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: And unrelated problem - you mistyped "choices" twice, but in different ways. In programming you must pay attention to details, otherwise your programs won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems (end to start):

1. missing `)` at the end... `""")#all different options` --> `"""))#all different options`
2. `:` that shouldn't be at `i = int(input("Enter the number of generations you want the model to run for (must be between 5 and 25 inclusive")):`
3. `)` that shouldn't be at `print("setting the generation 0 values"))`
4. same as 1 in line 48

Checking matching brackets and such after this kind of error is very useful :)

Fixed version:

```
print(" Greenfly Population Model")
chocies=[]


def option0():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("GOOD BYE")
    time.sleep(1)
    # exiting the loop

def option1():
    if choies==[]:
        print("Set the Generation 0 values!")
    else:
        print(chocies[:])
def option2():
    print("Display the Generation 0 values")


def option3():
    print("Run the model")

def option4():
    print("Export data")

def option5():
    print("Quit")





import time#for option 0
while True:#to keep the program continuous
    option=int(input("""
    High Scores


0- Exit
1- Show score
2- Add a score
3- Delete a score
4 - Sort the score in ascending order
5- Sort the score in descending order
"""))#all different options


s = int(input("from the menu above please pick your choice"))
print("setting the generation 0 values")
i = int(input("Enter the number of generations you want the model to run for (must be between 5 and 25 inclusive"))
m = int(input("Choose adult survival rate between 0 and 1:"))
o = int(input("Choose Juvenile survival rate between 0 and 1:"))
n = int(input("Choose Senile survival rate between 0 and 1:"))
r = int(input("please enter the initial numbers of juvenile:"))
a = int(input("please enter the initial numbers of adults:"))
i = int(input("please enter the initial numbers of seniles:"))
v = int(input("please enter the initial numbers of the adults:"))

print(s)
print(i)
print(m)
print(o)
print(n)
print(r)
print(a)
print(i)
print(v)



print(" Greenfly Population Model")
option=int(input("""
High Scores


0- Exit
1- Show score
2- Add a score
3- Delete a score
4 - Sort the score in ascending order
5 - Sort the score in descending order
"""))#all different options
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what I've done so far

```
print(" Greenfly Population Model")

chocies=[]


def option0():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("GOOD BYE")
    time.sleep(1)
    # exiting the loop

def option1():
    if chocies==[]:
        print("Set the Generation 0 values!")
    else:
        print(chocies[:])
def option2():
    print("Display the Generation 0 values")


def option3():
    print("Run the model")

def option4():
    print("Export data")

def option5():
    print("Quit")





import time#for option 0
while True:#to keep the program continuous
    option=int(input("""

("""
print(" Greenfly Population Model")
chocies=[]


def option0():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("GOOD BYE")
    time.sleep(1)
    # exiting the loop

def option1():
    if choies==[]:
        print("Set the Generation 0 values!")
    else:
        print(chocies[:])
def option2():
    print("Display the Generation 0 values")


def option3():
    print("Run the model")

def option4():
    print("Export data")

def option5():
    print("Quit")


    High Scores

("""
0- Exit
1- Show score
2- Add a score
3- Delete a score
4 - Sort the score in ascending order
5- Sort the score in descending order
""")#all different options


s = int(input("from the menu above please pick your choice"))
print("setting the generation 0 values"))
i = int(input("Enter the number of generations you want the model to run for (must be between 5 and 25 inclusive")):
m = int(input("Choose adult survival rate between 0 and 1:"))
o = int(input("Choose Juvenile survival rate between 0 and 1:"))
n = int(input("Choose Senile survival rate between 0 and 1:"))
r = int(input("please enter the initial numbers of juvenile:"))
a = int(input("please enter the initial numbers of adults:"))
i = int(input("please enter the initial numbers of seniles:"))
v = int(input("please enter the initial numbers of the adults:"))

print(s)
print(i)
print(m)
print(o)
print(n)
print(r)
print(a)
print(i)
print(v)


("""
print(" Greenfly Population Model")
option=int(input
High Scores


0- Exit
1- Show score
2- Add a score
3- Delete a score
4 - Sort the score in ascending order
5 - Sort the score in descending order
#all different options


""")


import time#for option 0
while True:#to keep the program continuous
    option=int(input("""
    High Scores


0- Exit
1- Show score
2- Add a score
3- Delete a score
4 - Sort the score in ascending order
5- Sort the score in descending order
"""))#all different options


s = int(input("from the menu above please pick your choice"))
print("setting the generation 0 values")
i = int(input("Enter the number of generations you want the model to run for (must be between 5 and 25 inclusive"))
m = int(input("Choose adult survival rate between 0 and 1:"))
o = int(input("Choose Juvenile survival rate between 0 and 1:"))
n = int(input("Choose Senile survival rate between 0 and 1:"))
r = int(input("please enter the initial numbers of juvenile:"))
a = int(input("please enter the initial numbers of adults:"))
i = int(input("please enter the initial numbers of seniles:"))
v = int(input("please enter the initial numbers of the adults:"))

print(s)
print(i)
print(m)
print(o)
print(n)
print(r)
print(a)
print(i)
print(v)



print(" Greenfly Population Model")
option=int(input("""
High Scores


0- Exit
1- Show score
2- Add a score
3- Delete a score
4 - Sort the score in ascending order
5 - Sort the score in descending order
"""))#all different options
```